# Prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

*Problem:* Prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. 
The book where I encountered this problem had the following hint:

> We make a polynomial with integer coefficients called $f(x)$ that $f(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=0$. (Why?)

Accepting this I solved the problem like this:
If $x=\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ then $x^2=5+2\sqrt{6}$ and so $(x^2-5)^2=24$ thus:
$$x^4-10x^2-1=0$$
But I want to know the reason that we should do this.

Comment: @Arthur: You're absolutely right. I forgot the rational root theorem!

Comment: To show $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3$ is irrational, it is enough to show that your $f(x)$ cannot have rational roots - which is sometimes simpler.  Of course, you do not **have** to do this, there are other ways as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), states that if a rational number solves a given polynomial equation with integer coefficients, then it must be possible to write that number as $\frac pq$ where $p$ is an integer that divides the constant term, and $q$ is an integer that divides the highest-degree coefficient.

In this case we only need to check $\pm 1$, which clearly does not solve the equation. Thus there are no rational numbers that solves $x^4 - 10x^2 - 1 = 0$.

Comment: Your statement of RRT is incorrect without assuming the necessary condition that  $\,p.q\,$ are coprime, e.g.  $\, x = 2/4\,$ is a root of $\,2x-1\,$ but $\,4\nmid 2,\ 2\nmid 1.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Better?

Answer (score 9):

An easy way to see this is to notice that
 $$(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)^2 = 5+2\sqrt 6.$$

Now, if $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ is rational, then so is its square. This implies that $(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3)^2 - 5 = 2\sqrt6$ is rational - a contradiction. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Directly:

If
$r = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$
is rational,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{r}
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}\\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}\dfrac{-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}{-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}}\\
&=-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\\
\end{array}
$

is also rational.

Adding and subtracting these,
$\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$
are rational.

Answer (score 3):

More generally,
suppose
$r
=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}
$
is rational,
where
$a$ and $b$
are positive integers.

Then
$r(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})
=a-b
$
so
$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}
=\dfrac{a-b}{r}
$
is also rational.

Adding and subtracting these,
$\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$
are rational.

Therefore,
if either or both
of
$\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$
are irrational,
then
$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$
is irrational
(and similarly for
$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$).

This might form a basis
for a proof that
$\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{a_k}
$
is irrational
under suitable assumptions on the
$a_k$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the way you normally prove $\sqrt2$ is irrational.

Let $x/y = \sqrt2 + \sqrt3$ where x and y are integers with no common factors.

You have

$x^4-10\cdot x^2y^2 + y^4 = 0$

So

$(x^2 - y^2)^2 - 8 \cdot x^2y^2 = 0$

$(x^2 - y^2)^2 = 8 \cdot x^2y^2$

Because the left side is divisible by 4, $x^2 - y^2$ is divisible by $2$.
Thus, x and y are the same parity. Since there are no common factors, they are both odd.

Let $x^2-y^2 = 2m$ where m is an integer.

$m^2 = 2\cdot x^2y^2$

m must be even. Let $m=2n$.

$4n^2 = 2\cdot x^2y^2$

$2n^2 = x^2y^2$

So $x^2y^2$ is even. This means one of x and y is even which is a contradiction.