# Prove $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, irrational-numbers

If it is assumed that $\sqrt{3}$ is known to be irrational (not the case for $\sqrt{5}$), then prove that $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is irrational.

My approach:

Assume that $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is rational. Then there exist coprime integers $p$ and $q$ so that $\frac{p}{q}$ is rational and $\frac{p}{q}=\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$. Thus $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^2=2(4+\sqrt{15})=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$, which implies that $p^2$ is even, so $p$ is also even. Let $p:=2m$ for some integer $m$, then $p^2=4m^2$. Thus $q^2(4+\sqrt{15})=2m^2$, which implies that $q^2$ is even, and so $q$ is even. But this contradicts that $p$ and $q$ are coprime, and we arrive at a contradiction.

> My way of proving this does not use the fact that $\sqrt{3}$ is
>   irrational. Please let me know if my proof is correct, and how to use
>   the above mentioned fact.

Comment: $2(4+\sqrt{15})$ is not even an integer, so just because there is a factor of $2$, does not mean that $p^2$ is even.  For example, I can write $3 = 2(1.5) = p$, but that doesn't mean $p$ must be even simply because I wrote it as $2 \times 1.5$.

Comment: After you get to $2(4+\sqrt{15})$, you just need to show that $\sqrt{15}$ is irrational.

Comment: If we assume that $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ is rational then its square must also be rational. So we are then assuming that $(4+\sqrt{15})$ is rational.

Comment: This is not the sort of proof where writing a rational number as $p/q$ helps. Just keep track of things like "the sum/product of two rational numbers is rational."

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks, got the proof the right way now.

Comment: Not completely duplicate, bue a similar method applies: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913934/process-to-show-that-sqrt-2-sqrt3-3-is-irrational

Comment: Any irrational number plus another irrational number is also an irrational number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is from here:

[Prove that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885802/prove-that-sqrt2-sqrt3-is-irrational/1886137)

More generally,
suppose
$r
=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}
$
is rational,
where
$a$ and $b$
are positive integers.

Then
$r(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})
=a-b
$
so
$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}
=\dfrac{a-b}{r}
$
is also rational.

Adding and subtracting these,
$\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$
are rational.

Therefore,
if either or both
of
$\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$
are irrational,
then
$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$
is irrational
(and similarly for
$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$).

Comment: Yes, that's the one method that I used and was thinking about posting :)

Comment: Post first, think later. More points that way:)

Comment: @martycohen good philosophy.  Also let's others think while you thinking.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x=\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5$. Then:

$$(x - \sqrt 3)^2 = 5$$
$$x^2 - 2 \sqrt 3 x + 3 = 5$$
$$x^2 - 2 = 2 \sqrt 3 x$$
$$(x^2 - 2)^2 = 12 x^2$$
$$x^4 -16 x^2 + 4 = 0$$

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), if the last equation had rational roots then they would be integer divisors of $4$. But none of $\pm1, \pm2,\pm4$ are roots, so $x$ must be irrational.

Answer (score 3):

If $\sqrt3+\sqrt5=x$ is rational, then $5=(x-\sqrt3)^2=x^2-2\sqrt3x+3$, and

$$\sqrt3=\frac{x^2-2}{2x}$$

But then $\sqrt3$ is also rational. However, we know that $\sqrt3$ is irrational, so $x$ is also irrational.

---

And we know $\sqrt3$ is irrational by the usual argument: is $\sqrt3=p/q$, with coprime integers $p$ and $q$, then $p^2=3q^2$. Hence $3$ divides $p$, but then $9$ divides $p^2$ and $3$ divides $q$, so $p$ and $q$ are not coprime, contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

> If $\sqrt{15}=p/q$ is rational and $\sqrt3$ is irrational then $\sqrt5=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{\sqrt3}=\frac{p}{q\sqrt3}$ so
>   $$5=\sqrt5^2=\frac{p^2}{3q^2}.$$
>   Hence $3$ appears an odd number of times in the prime factorisation of $5,$ a contradiction.

---

Hope this helps.

---

P.S. I don't know what I was thinking in putting the old Hint I here.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "3 appears an odd number of times in 5"?

Comment: Both $5$ and $\frac{p^2}{3q^2}$ are rational, so we can look at their factorisation into the form $$\prod\limits_ip_i^{n_i}$$ where $p_i$ are primes and $n_i$ might be negative. Since $5=\frac{p^2}{3q^2}$ we conclude that "3 appears an odd number of times in" the factorisation of $5.$

Comment: What's wrong with 3 appearing an odd number of times in 5?

Comment: Well, the factorisation of $5$ is unique, and that is $5=5$, with $3$ appearing $0$ times, while $0$ is even.

Comment: I) isn't a contradiction.  Root (5) *is* irrational.

Comment: @fleablood I am not saying it is a contradiction. I am trying to determine if  $\sqrt5$ is irrational or not from the given conditions.

Comment: @fleablood I edited the answer. Thanks for pointing out that strange hint.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5 = p/q; p,q \in \mathbb Z $ then...

$\sqrt 5 = p/q - \sqrt 3$

$5 = (p/q)^2 - 2 (p/q)\sqrt 3 +3$

$2 (p/q)\sqrt 3 = (p/q)^2 - 2$

$\sqrt 3 = (p/2q) - (q/p) $ which is rational.  Which is a contradiction as you had already proven that.

.....

However if you hadn't...

This is not the easiest but

If $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt 5 = p/q $

$3 + 2\sqrt {15} + 5 = p^2/q^2$

$\sqrt {15} = p^2/2q^2 - 4 = a/b $

Where $a = p^2- 8q^2; b=2q^2$.

Let $a= 3^j5^k c; 3^l5^m d $ where $c,d $ don't have any factors of $3$ or $5$.  ($j,k,l,m $ may be $0$)

$15 =\frac {3^{2j}5^{2k}c}{3^{2l}5^{2m}d}$

$3^{2l+1}5^{2m+1}c = 3^{2j}5^{2k} d$

But the LHS had an odd number of factors of 3 and 5, while the RHS has even (or 0) number of factors of 3 and 5 so they can't be equal.